# Store values into keys with scrapy

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract information from a website like price and store that as values in a dictionary. However, I'm trying to learn scrapy so I'd like to know how to achieve this with it.

Here's how it would look like with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`

```
import numpy as np
import requests as r
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeauitfulSoup

html = ['https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=1&_sop=16',
       'https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=2&_sop=16',
       'https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=3&_sop=16',
       'https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=4&_sop=16',
       'https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=5&_sop=16']

data = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(0, len(html):
    r = requests.get(html[i])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    name = soup.select(".s-item__title")
    value = soup.select(".ITALIC")
    for n, v in zip(name, value):
        data["card"].append(n.text.strip())
        data["price"].append(v.text.strip())
```

Here's what I have tried with scrapy but I do not get any values after looking at the json output. I just get the links, how do I get the output like the code above?:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.item import Field
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

html = np.array(['https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=1&_sop=16',
       'https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=2&_sop=16',
       'https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=3&_sop=16',
       'https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=4&_sop=16',
       'https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=5&_sop=16'],
      dtype=object)

url = pd.DataFrame(html, columns=['data'])

class StatisticsItem(scrapy.Item):
    statistics_div = Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
    url = Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())


class StatisticsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'statistics'
    start_urls = url.data.values

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        
        table = response.xpath("//div[@class='s-item__price']").get()

        loader = ItemLoader(StatisticsItem())
        loader.add_value('values', table)
        loader.add_value('url', response.url)
        yield loader.load_item()


process = CrawlerProcess(
    settings={
        'FEED_URI': 'ebay_data.json',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'jsonlines'
    }
)
process.crawl(StatisticsSpider)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the custom_settings to write to 'cards_info.json' with json format.

Inside parse I go through each card on the page (see xpath) and get the card's title and price, then I yield them. Scrapy will write them into 'cards_info.json'.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Field
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst


class StatisticsItem(scrapy.Item):
    statistics_div = Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
    url = Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())


class StatisticsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'statistics'
    start_urls = ['https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=1&_sop=16',
                     'https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=2&_sop=16',
                     'https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=3&_sop=16',
                     'https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=4&_sop=16',
                     'https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=5&_sop=16']

    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_URI': 'cards_info.json'
    }
    
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        all_cards = response.xpath('//div[@class="s-item__wrapper clearfix"]')
        for card in all_cards:
            name = card.xpath('.//h3/text()').get()
            price = card.xpath('.//span[@class="s-item__price"]//text()').get()
            # now do whatever you want, append to dictionary, yield as item.
            # example with yield:
            yield {
                'card': name,
                'price': price
            }
```

Output:

```py
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=1&_sop=16>
{'card': 'Pokemon 1st Edition Shadowless Base Set 11 Blister Booster Pack Lot - DM To Buy!', 'price': '£93,805.84'}
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=1&_sop=16>
{'card': 'Pokemon Team Rocket Complete Complete 83/82, German, 1. Edition', 'price': '£102,026.04'}
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Collectable-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_2316999?LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=1&_sop=16>
{'card': 'Yugioh E Hero Pit Boss 2013 World Championship Prize Card BGS 9.5 Gem Mint', 'price': '£100,000.00'}
...
...
```

cards_info.json:

```json
[
{"card": "1999 Pokemon Base Set Booster Box GREEN WING", "price": "\u00a340,000.00"},
{"card": "1996 MEDIA FACTORY POKEMON NO RARITY BASE SET CHARIZARD 006 BECKETT BGS MINT 9 ", "price": "\u00a339,999.99"},
{"card": "Yugioh - BGS8.5 Jump Festa Blue Eyes White Dragon -1999 - Limited - PSA", "price": "\u00a340,000.00"},
{"card": "PSA 8 CHARIZARD 1999 POKEMON 1ST EDITION THICK STAMP SHADOWLESS #4 HOLO NM-MINT", "price": "\u00a337,224.53"},
{"card": "PSA 9 MINT Pok\u00e9mon Play Promo 50000 PTS Gold Star Japanese Pokemon", "price": "\u00a338,261.06"},
...
...
]
```

Comment: I managed to get this to work by integrating it with mine above!